# How to use hook_url_outbound_alter for emails only?

Tags: uri

I have a Rule set up that sends a mail to a certain user with a link to a certain node. This link is altered using `hook_url_outbound_alter` to include additional details.

The problem is that hook_url_outbound_alter also alters the URL everywhere else. Closing an overlay on the node view page rewrites the URL, clearing the cache (admin toolbar + devel) on the node pages rewrites the URL and so on.

I already attempted to check for an absolute URL in `$options`, but that does not solve the problems above.

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if (preg_match('|^node/([0-9]*)|', $path, $matches) && $options['absolute'] {
      $options['query']['parameter'] = $foo;
    }
  }
}
```

Can I use `hook_url_outbound_alter()` to only alter URLs when it was invoked from a specific module or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use `hook_url_outbound_alter()` to only alter URLs when it was invoked from a specific module or something?

You cannot, if that module doesn't put in `$options` (the same argument passed to [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7.x)) something that makes you understand that. To make an example, [`entity_uri()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/entity_uri/7.x) uses `$options['entity_type']` and `$options['entity']`; if you were trying to intercept the calls to `url()` done from `entity_uri()`, you could check the presence of those options.
Otherwise, the context given to `hook_url_outbound_alter()` doesn't allow to understand which module called `url()`. Maybe you could get that using debugging functions, but I am not sure I would put that kind of code in a module.

Since you seem to trying to alter links in an email sent from Drupal, you could implement [`hook_mail_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7.x), assuming the emails are sent using the correct way of sending them with Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am sending the mails with rules, so there is no way to add any other metadata to `$options`. Do you know if `hook_mail_alter()` works with rules?

Comment: As long as the module uses `drupal_mail()`, it works. Alternatively, if the Rules module doesn't use `drupal_mail()` to send emails, I would create a rule action to do what you need.